# Add to cart button enabled if subscriber seller

Tags: 8, commerce

I want to create a marketplace. Each seller will be able to create a shop and products that will be displayed to all visitors.

- A non-subscriber (free) will have on his product a button "Add to cart" not clickable. The products can not be ordered.
- A subscriber (paid) will have on his product a button "Add to cart" clickable. The products can be ordered.

How to do this ?

How do I create subscriptions with an end date with drupal ?

Comment: You want idea about how to do or code?

Comment: @A Ajay Reddy I do not know, the simplest method to do this

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be for Drupal 7 with respect to current code to your final question of functionality:
 - After making sure both the rest of your structure is in place, Add the Rules watchdog that will "listen" for the role or lack thereof
   and then do not only 'it' but perhaps other things for example display a popup message. It would be possible to change the look or color of the button as well. Requirement: Rules module. Rules UI will have it write the code for you, that you can then save to code if you want.
 - With a rule stating normal code behavior not having fired or reverting to normal behavior after logging in, then the button will do as it was coded to do.

Subscriptions with an end date in Drupal by marrying a subscription to a role by https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license not released for 8 production yet whereby you do all the magic of billing: Commerce Billing is an option in Drupal 7, method, cycle, grace period, and expire or downgrade the role as you wish upon expiration. From a step point-of-view, this step precedes the rules, as this will be the basis for rules. "commerce_billing" is only available for Drupal 7 at this time with respect to billing anyway, and the projects don't show a Drupal 8 version being started yet. That's why my answer is for Drupal 7 only at this time, except when one module may be ready but calls itself "dev", and the other is not yet started.

Comment: thank you for your explanations. What do you think of this module for druppal 8 https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_license

Comment: The fact is no release for it yet, means it is still in code development, and the other one I mentioned, incorrectly "_billing" https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_billy is not in code yet means you can get there in Drupal version 7, just not in 8 until it or you get it to that Drupal 7 functionality.